# How to get Json Response in Arraylist from List<Item> using RxJava and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-kotlin

Facing Problem on getting Response in ArrayList.

I have following Respose on String value

```
 var res_message: String = ""
 res_message = "${result.vehicletypes} "
```

Getting below Value on this String

```
     [VehicleType(_id=1, vehicleType=Hatchback, __v=0), 
      VehicleType(_id=2, vehicleType=Maruti, __v=0), 
      VehicleType(_id=3, vehicleType=Honda, __v=0), 
      VehicleType(_id=4, vehicleType=Bike, __v=0)]
```

Retrofit Result is

```
 vehicletypes = {ArrayList@6055}  size = 4
 0 = {Model$VehicleType@6058} "VehicleType(_id=1, 
vehicleType=Hatchback, __v=0)"
 1 = {Model$VehicleType@6059} "VehicleType(_id=2, 
 vehicleType=Maruti, __v=0)"
  2 = {Model$VehicleType@6060} "VehicleType(_id=3, 
 vehicleType=Honda, __v=0)"
  3 = {Model$VehicleType@6061} "VehicleType(_id=4, 
  vehicleType=Bike, __v=0)"
```

Below Code snippest sending request to API.

```
            disposable = apiServices.getVehicle(token)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    { result ->


                        res_message = "${result.vehicletypes} "
                        Log.d("Type==", res_message)
                    },
                    { error ->
                        res_message = "${error.message}"
                        // validateToken()
                    }
            )
```

*Model Class*

```
  data class Vehicles(val success: Boolean, val vehicletypes: List<VehicleType>, val message: String)
  data class VehicleType(val _id: String, val vehicleType: String, val __v: String)
```

I want to get this value on Arralist **VehicleType** List on below **vehicleListArray**

```
   private var vehicleListArray: ArrayList<Model.VehicleType>? = null
```

How we can achieve this. 
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What is return type of fun getPeople() method in apiService definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution I have to handle Respose as below code snippet.

```
private fun getVehicleType() { 
    disposable?.add(apiServices.getVehicle(token)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse, this::handleError))
}

private fun handleResponse(vehicles: Model.Vehicles) {
    VehiclesArrayList = ArrayList(vehicles.vehicletypes)
    Log.d("type==","n--"+VehiclesArrayList )
    mAdapter = DataAdapter(VehiclesArrayList !!, this)
    v_android_list.adapter = mAdapter
}

private fun handleError(error: Throwable) {
    Log.d("type", error.localizedMessage)
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error ${error.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you are trying to parse is a response from a service that is able to send you propper format for lists (eg Json) than
Retrofit can handle parsing lists with ease.

In your apiService definition:

```
fun getPeople(token: Whatever): Observable<List<VehicleType>>
```

And if you don't have it already:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
```

Comment: Thank you @muminers I will try.

Comment: I would use Flowable instead of Observable but the answer it´s Ok! :thumbsup:

Comment: @axierjhtjz Good you've pointed it out. Acctually it isn't easy to decide in my opinion. Here is piece of doc that covers this subject:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#observable-and-flowable

Comment: Yep, not easy to make a pick, that´s why I said "I would use". Good read by the way.

Comment: @axierjhtjz why not Single, are you expect more values? for simple POST it's ok to use Completable